# Using range command to iterate url for webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web page that has a number in the back of url ranging from 1. so I'm trying to use range option to iterate the url but something is not working, I am not sure what the issue is....

I have to be honest I have modified a code that I barely managed to make it read a csv file that had a list of urls.

The website goes like this

```
https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,1
https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,2
https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,3
https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,4
```

Jupiter notebook is not showing me any results which is more concerning than an error message.....

`````
````
    ````

    import bs4 as bs
    import urllib.request
    import csv
    import numpy as np

    base_url = "https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,"
    url_list =[]


    def extract(gameurl):
        req = urllib.request.Request(gameurl,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
        infopage = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"col-md-8 col-lg-8"})
        core_list =[]

        for credits in infopage:
            niceHeaderTitle = credits.find_all("h1", {"class":"niceHeaderTitle"})
            name = niceHeaderTitle[0].text

            Titles = credits.find_all("h3", {"class":"clean"})

            Titles = [title.get_text() for title in Titles]

            tr = credits.find_all("tr")

            for i in range(len(tr)):
                row = tr[i].get_text(strip=True)
                if row in Titles:
                    title = row
                elif len(row) > 1:
                    games=[name,title,row]
                    core_list.append(games)

            core_list = np.matrix(core_list)

            return core_list


    def csv_write(url_data):
        with open ('human_resource.csv','a',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            writer=csv.writer(file)
            for row in url_data:
                writer.writerow(row)

    for url in url_list:
        url = range(1,100)
        link = base_url + url            
        url_data = extract(link)
        csv_write(url_data)

    ````
`````

Comment: "url_list" is empty therefore the for-loop isn't executed.

Comment: Thanks! can you be more specific?? I'm not sure what to do